# CSS: Chart getting out of the container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure where is this controlled from, can you point me out? I'm new to CSS.

The chart gets of the container when you resize the window. Where do you control this in CSS?
I don't need to resize the chart, at least just hide it? is that possible?

[image]

I'm using twitter bootstrap and here is the HTML generated

```
  <div class='row-fluid'>
    <div class='span9'>
      <div class='box'>
        <div class='box-content padded' style='text-align: center'>
          <div id='graphs' style='width:860px; margin:0 auto;' title='test'>
            <div id='chart' style='display: inline-block;' title='test'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='span3'>
      <div class='box'>
        <div class='box-content padded'>
          Hosts ...
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='box'>
        <div class='box-content padded'>
          <b> Services ... </b>
          <br> .... </br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing the chart to fit the parent container is easy; just use `width:100%` on the graph. So in your code, replace this code:

```
<div id='graphs' style='width:860px; margin:0 auto;' title='test'>
```

with this code:

```
<div id='graphs' style='width:100%; margin:0 auto;' title='test'>
```

What that does is sets the graph width as a percentage of the parent element, which is the `div` of class `box-content padded`. Thus, if we set the `width` to `100%`, the graph always matches the size of the container.

Comment: I would highly suggest going through a documentation. If you're totally new, try W3Schools. If you're more experienced with CSS, try the MDN.